# kubernetes deployment failed with skaffold

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skaffold

**I'm working on a microservices app by docker , kubernetes and skaffold
and this is my skaffold config file**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: mohamedl3zb/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
    - image: mohamedl3zb/tickets
      context: tickets
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
```

**I get this error**

```
exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: kubectl create: running [kubectl --context docker-desktop create --dry-run=client -oyaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\auth-depl.yaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\auth-mongo-depl.yaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\ingress-srv.yaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\nats-depl.yaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\tickets-depl.yaml -f C:\Users\Mohamed Salah\Desktop\ticket-app\infra\k8s\tickets-mongo.depl.yaml]
 - stdout: "apiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n  name: auth-depl\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  replicas: 1\n  selector:\n    matchLabels:\n      app: auth\n  template:\n    metadata:\n      labels:\n        app: auth\n    spec:\n      containers:\n      - env:\n        - name: MONGO_URI\n  
        value: mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth\n        - name: JWT_KEY\n          valueFrom:\n            secretKeyRef:\n              key: JWT_KEY\n              name: jwt-secret-key\n        image: mohamedl3zb/auth\n        name: auth\n---\napiVersion: v1\nkind: Service\nmetadata:\n  name: auth-srv\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  ports:\n  - name: auth\n    port: 3000\n    protocol: TCP\n    targetPort: 3000\n  selector:\n    app: auth\n---\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n  name: auth-mongo-depl\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  replicas: 1\n  selector:\n    matchLabels:\n      app: auth-mongo\n  template:\n    metadata:\n      labels:\n        app: auth-mongo\n    spec:\n      containers:\n      - image: mongo\n        name: auth-mongo\n---\napiVersion: v1\nkind: Service\nmetadata:\n  name: auth-mongo-srv\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  ports:\n  - name: db\n    port: 27017\n    protocol: TCP\n    targetPort: 27017\n  selector:\n    app: auth-mongo\n---\napiVersion: extensions/v1beta1\nkind: Ingress\nmetadata:\n  annotations:\n    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx\n    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: \"true\"\n  name: ingress-service\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  rules:\n  - host: ticketing.dev\n    http:\n      paths:\n      - backend:\n          serviceName: auth-srv\n          servicePort: 3000\n        path: /api/users/?(.*)\n      - backend:\n          serviceName: tickets-srv\n          servicePort: 3000\n        path: /api/tickets/?(.*)\n      - backend:\n          serviceName: orders-srv\n          servicePort: 3000\n        path: /api/orders/?(.*)\n      - backend:\n          serviceName: payments-srv\n          servicePort: 3000\n        path: /api/payments/?(.*)\n      - backend:\n          serviceName: client-srv\n          servicePort: 3000\n        path: /?(.*)\n---\napiVersion: v1\nkind: Service\nmetadata:\n  name: nats-srv\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  ports:\n  - name: clients\n    port: 4222\n    protocol: TCP\n  
  targetPort: 4222\n  - name: monitoring\n    port: 8222\n    protocol: TCP\n    targetPort: 8222\n  selector:\n    app: nats\n---\napiVersion: apps/v1\nkind: Deployment\nmetadata:\n  name: tickets-mongo-depl\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  replicas: 1\n  selector:\n    matchLabels:\n      app: tickets-mongo\n  template:\n    metadata:\n      labels:\n        app: tickets-mongo\n    spec:\n      containers:\n      - image: mongo\n        name: tickets-mongo\n---\napiVersion: v1\nkind: Service\nmetadata:\n  name: tickets-mongo-srv\n  namespace: default\nspec:\n  ports:\n  - name: db\n    port: 27017\n    protocol: TCP\n    targetPort: 27017\n  selector:\n    app: tickets-mongo\n"
 - stderr: "unable to recognize \"C:\\\\Users\\\\Mohamed Salah\\\\Desktop\\\\ticket-app\\\\infra\\\\k8s\\\\nats-depl.yaml\": no matches for kind \"Deplyment\" in version \"apps/v1\"\nerror validating \"C:\\\\Users\\\\Mohamed Salah\\\\Desktop\\\\ticket-app\\\\infra\\\\k8s\\\\tickets-depl.yaml\": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].valueFrom): unknown field \"fielsRef\" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVarSource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false\n"
 - cause: exit status 1
```

I'm working with docker desktop and kubernetes

Comment: Looks like a typo: `unknown field \"fielsRef\"`

Comment: i have fixed it but still gives me that error

Comment: so it is not fixed?

Comment: You seem to have a number of validation errors in your Kubernetes manifests.  The Google Cloud Shell Editor (ide.cloud.google.com), which is free, offers Kubernetes manifest validation and integrates with Skaffold.  This support is also available for VS Code and IntelliJ through the Cloud Code (cloud.google.com/code) extensions (also free).

Answer (score 0):

You've got two typos in your manifests that the admission controller is rejecting.

The first is `nats-depl.yaml` where `Deployment` is misspelled.

The second you mentioned already fixing in a comment, but I'll leave the relevant part of the error here for completeness:

`"C:\\\\Users\\\\Mohamed Salah\\\\Desktop\\\\ticket-app\\\\infra\\\\k8s\\\\tickets-depl.yaml\": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].valueFrom): unknown field \"fielsRef\" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVarSource`

Comment: fixed it but still gives me the same error

Comment: If you're still getting the exact same error than the typos are not fixed. You should probably double check the exact error message as there may be additional problems with the manifest files that are producing a similar error with slightly different output. The message should be fairly explicit about where the issue is just like the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to be this
"unknown field "fielsRef" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVarSource"